# Lusatia oath from 1422

Tags: middle-ages, catholic-church

Citizens of [Lusatia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusatia) are claimed to have been made to take an oath in 1422, starting with the following words

> Die Ketzer und in dem christlichen Glauben irresame Leute zu tilgen und zu verderben

What's the full text of the oath?

Comment: You **may** found more on this oath in *"Der Oberlausitzer Hussitenkrieg und das Land der Sechsstädte unter Kaiser Sigmund"*, vol. 1 by Richard Jecht. According to the [TOC](http://d-nb.info/998463620/04), it treats an "oath against the heretics" in the year 1422 on p. 50.